# Expanding AlwaysOn Availability Groups with Replication Subscribers

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, transactional-replication

I have query regarding "AlwaysOn Availability Groups with Replication Subscribers"...

1. Can I add multiple publishers to a subscriber(which is part of availability group as a primary server)?
2. In which node can I configure distributer?
3. How do I configure the distributer?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I add multiple publishers to a subscriber(which is part of
>   availability group as a primary server)?

Yes, this is the [multiple publishers model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152567(v=sql.110).aspx) and is supported.

> In which node can I configure distributer?

The distribution database is *currently* not supported for use in AlwaysOn Availability Groups. The only supported method for transparent distributor failover is AlwaysOn Failover Cluster Instances.

> How do I configure the distributer?

You can configure it through [SSMS or T-SQL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151192(v=sql.110).aspx).

Comment: thanks for reply...but  answer of my second question is not satisfied my scenario..yesterday i successfully configured "AlwaysOn Availability Groups with Replication Subscribers"...and its running good..i configured distributer for replication on subscriber box(primary replica) and issue is after failover my primary replica goes down and also distributer ...so  my question is where to configure distributer for replication....

Comment: If you want HA for the distributor, put it on its' own FCI instance. Make it a VM, pretty much do anything but I would not put it on an instance using Availability Groups.